# how to raise a marker limit in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autoit

I've been searching about this for few days, but I think I only understand less than a half.

I'm creating a AutoIT application using Google Maps API V3 and free API key. When I add 1500 markers within 30 mins with 500~600ms delay each marker, my map won't be displayed anymore. It is just blank. I can't see the error message, but I think it's `"OVER QUERY LIMIT"`. Usually it will become normal after few hours or on the next day. The map is normal if I run it from another site (different IP address). It's also normal if I open the Google map through Google Maps website.

I don't understand that, because I supply the direct coordinate, so it doesn't spend up the geocode limit (I think). From what I read, the free account is entitled to 2,500 geocodes per day, I don't even use the geocode for adding the marker.

What is actually the limit for this? How many markers I could put on a map in 1 hour and in a day and what is the delay for each marker? If I know exactly the limitation, I can try to arrange my script to obey that rules.

Comment: There is no limit for markers

Comment: That was what I'm thinking before, but I tried it over and over again in these few days on 2 different physical locations (different ip address) to come into this conclusion. Or my code is incorrect (I'm going to edit my first post with small code)?

Comment: While I'm trying to add the code to first post, I'm just aware that my code ALWAYS geocode whatever the parameter/input. So when I supply direct coordinates, it still use geocode so I think that eat up the geocode limit. I'm going to revise my code, mean while could any body confirm that there is no limit for markers? How about delays for each marker? Thanks!

Comment: Geocoding will not be done automatically, when you didn't explicitly send a geocoding-request in your code  nothing will be geocoded.

Comment: I understand that. My current code will geocode any inputs including when I pass a coordinate (not address) to it which it's shouldn't (and dont need). I'm going to modify it and see how it's going. How much delay should I put for drawing each marker? Is 150ms or 200ms enough? Thanks, Dr. Molle!

Comment: You don't need any delay when you draw markers(as long as gecoding is not involved). When geocoding is involved, 150ms should be fine, because there is a limit of 10 requests per second for all webservices.

Comment: I find 200ms to be more reliable, as Dr.Molle said, in theory 150ms should suffice but I tend to end up with missed points. Out of curiosity why are you geocoding if you have the coordinates? If it's to re-project you can simply use a function to accomplish the same? Removing the geocoding would likely solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, Dr.Molle, thank you, Swires. Yes, I should not geocoding because I already have the coordinates. I'm geocoding them because I dont understand that :( But now I understand :) Yes, removing geocoding solve my problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Answer your own question with how you solved your problem. Will give other people a better ability to see how you solved it :)

Comment: @JonBecher: there is nothing special on how I solve it :) I realized that my code was doing geocoding each time it place a marker. I just modified it so it will not geocode if the parameter passed is a valid coordinate.

Comment: [@michaels](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3113225/michaels) I don't think you got what I meant. Use the answer box below to answer your own question, so that it will be easier for others to see how you got to your solution.